# (correctly) Removing Laravel application from AWS server without deleting instance

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'd like to completely remove an old Laravel application that I upload as a test version of my AWS Instance. I'd like to upload a newer fresh updated version of that application so I'd like to -safely- remove old one and upload the new one.

I'd like to avoid -if possible- deploy a new instance so I don't have to install and configure all once again.

Application path is var/www/.

Should I just simply delete with terminal all files within this path and upload the new one in this path? Or there is a better practice for this purpose?

Thanks all,

Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of removing a Laravel project is just removing the directory that contains the desired project. So basically you could just remove the old project and deploy the new one and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

**you can delete your project with rm -rf your_project_path command**